# How to get not null Runtime created components names after setName(String);?

Tags: java

I´m building a swing aplication , which has all visual components runtime created on a single class. Every control shows fine. Any time a component is declared, a `component.setName(String);` is placed. 
The problem is that when trying to access that names, via `component.getName();`, even within the same class instance, I get null result.

```
for(Component c:this.getFrame().getComponents()) {
    System.out.println(c.getName());
}
```

`getFrame`is just an standar getter returning main Jframe.
That just print one null, but frame is populated with components.

Expected result should be f.e. "Calculate" instead of null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show that you get the value `null` and not the strings you assign. Most likely you are setting the names on the wrong objects or read it from different objects.

Comment: If you’re using Swing, that probably means your frame is a JFrame, in which case you did not add anything to the JFrame itself.  JFrame implements [RootPaneContainer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html), which means all of the child components are actually children of the content pane.  Try `this.getFrame().getContentPane().getComponents()` instead.

Comment: Already tried, and got this results: null.glassPane
null.layeredPane

Answer (score 1):

it´s been a while:
I think I have find the way to solve this q, anyway feedback´swelcome.
I´m afraid it was my fault, cause i didn´t explained well the problem.
The point are containers (readJFrames, JPanel or whatever).
If you´ve got a JPanel inside, let´s say a JFrame, you´ll have to call getComponents of that panel, and so on...
Hope it solves the q. 
Thanks anybody who kept on.